# C# datatable, duplicate data

Tags: c#

For testing I would like to expand my result set. I have a `DataTable dt` that has 7 or so results. I would like to do something like:

`dt.Rows.Add(dt);` a few times, just to make the data set larger.

I also tried `dt.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[0]);`

The first gave an error about the type, the second said the row already existed.

Comment: Are you really adding the correct type then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something like what's below.  Basically generate a new row using the values from the existing row.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
dt.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
```

Comment: This is exactly what my answer was going to be. @James hit on the reasons why the code fails, but didn't provide a solution as you did so +1 to you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy values to new row:

```
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row.ItemArray = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first item fails because the function expects a `DataRow` param.

The second item fails, because you are trying to add an item from the table, so it will inherently exist.

Try:

```
DataTable dt;
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["field"] = "Some Value";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Check out the [DataRow Class article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx)